# Uncaught TypeError: loadLink.offset() is undefined

Tags: javascript

Here is the JS, which works fine, but throws an error Uncaught TypeError: loadLink.offset() is undefined. Not sure how much more info I can give.

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var loadLink = $('#nav-load'), loadStatus = 0;
    $(window).scroll (function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() + 50 > loadLink.offset().top) {
            var urlNext = loadLink.find('a').attr('href');
            if (urlNext !== undefined && loadStatus == 0) {
                loadStatus = 1;
                $.ajax({
                    url: urlNext,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        ShowLoading();
                    },            
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#bottom-nav').remove();
                        $('#content').append($('#content', data).html()).after($('#bottom-nav'));
                        window.history.pushState("", "", urlNext);
                        HideLoading();
                        loadStatus = 0, loadLink = $('#nav-load');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                loadLink.remove();
            };
        };
    });  
    
});
```

Comment: Show your html :)

Comment: You need to change your snippet

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](//api.jquery.com/offset) to learn when `offset` returns `undefined`? Have you tried [searching similar questions on Google](//google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+js+jquery+offset+returns+undefined)?

Comment: Well, this is it, it will not let me edit post.

Comment: So `var loadLink = $('#nav-load')` did not find the element.

Comment: Is the element with the id of `nav-load` on the page when it loads?

Comment: <div class="bottom-nav ignore-select" id="bottom-nav">
     <div class="nav-load" id="nav-load">[next-link]Load more[/next-link]</div>